# Tensorflow / keras issue when optimizing with optuna

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network, optuna

I'm pretty new to machine learning, I've been trying to teach myself neural networks from following sentdex tutorials. I followed his tutorial on using recurrent neural networks for predicting the price of various crypto-currencies and succeeded after changing NumPy arrays and some of the syntax. Now I've been trying to add optimization to it since I've noticed just how drastically overfitting can change with tweaking the learning rate and layers of the network.

The code of the one that works with no errors is this one
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VNeRLeGBByEIdMVwXcbsOR8xjWwsHHoQ?usp=sharing

It looks like I just copied and pasted the code but this is just because I was troubleshooting the code and I just referencing this one with the one I followed from the tutorial and then continued with this one after I got it working.

I've been trying to follow the tutorials for optuna and code I found for optimizing networks online so I'm trying to add it from these sources

https://github.com/optuna/optuna/blob/master/examples/tensorflow/tensorflow_eager_simple.py

https://github.com/optuna/optuna/blob/master/examples/keras/keras_integration.py

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-tANR7FopTX_ipAUCJmfZ2h_-iu3ljD_?usp=sharing

and what I'm trying to make is this

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cgnz7XUwnhfBvsA9whCXKQ3PrRs_sddh?usp=sharing

this is where I'm getting errors. At first, when I was making this post I was stuck on

ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 50, 2) are incompatible

but then I remembered that in the one I followed the tutorial on I needed one recurrent layer without
return_sequences=True before I continued with Dense layers

so I tried to add another recurrent layer without returning sequences and now I'm getting this

ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_20 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 2)

I'm not entirely certain where to go from here. I feel like I'm just doing something stupid, I was stuck on trying to figure out how to use a convolutional neural network from a tutorial on my own images for a year because I was reshaping instead of resizing the pictures. I hope it's something simple like that.

Thanks for all your guy's help, you guys have been very helpful since I've started my programming journey.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue was in building the model using optuna. After several errors and fixing a lot of issues, I got it all working. If anyone's interested here's the section relevant to the errors I was getting.

```
    def create_model(trial):
# We optimize the numbers of layers, their units and weight decay parameter.

n_layers = trial.suggest_int("n_layers", 3, 20)
weight_decay = trial.suggest_float("weight_decay", 1e-100, 1e-1, log=True)
lr = trial.suggest_float("lr", 1e-12, 1e-1, log=True)
  
momentum = trial.suggest_float("momentum", 0.0, 1.0)
```

## model = tf.keras.Sequential()

#model.add(Dropout(0.1))

```
for i in range(n_layers):
    
    dropout = trial.suggest_float("dropout_l{}".format(i), 0.05, 0.5)

    num_hidden = trial.suggest_int("n_units_l{}".format(i), 32, 256, log=True)

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(LSTM(num_hidden, input_shape=(train_x.shape[1:]), return_sequences=True))

    model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout)) 
    
    model.add(LSTM(num_hidden))

    model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout)) 
    
    model.add(Dense(num_hidden, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dropout(rate=dropout))
```

## model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

```
    model.add(Dense(
            num_hidden,
            activation="relu",
            kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(weight_decay)
        )
    )
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax', kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))
    #tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(weight_decay)))

        # Compile model.
model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=lr, momentum=momentum, nesterov=True),
    loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)

return model
```

and if you want to see all of the code for it here's what I have so far, needs a lot of tidying up but it works. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1cgnz7XUwnhfBvsA9whCXKQ3PrRs_sddh?usp=sharing